# Generation of an unknown column jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, jpa-2.0

this is my entity class:

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "EMP_EXPORTATEUR")
    public class EMPExportateur implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8981044305302155626L;
        @Id
        //@Basic(optional = false)
        //@NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 19)
        @Column(name = "EXP_CODE")
        private String expCode;
        @Size(max = 255)
        @Column(name = "EXP_NAME")
        private String expName;
        @Embedded
        private AdresseEmbeddable adresse;
        @Embedded
        @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "indicatifPays", column =
                   @Column(name = "TELFIX_COUN_COD")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "numeroTelephone", column =
                   @Column(name = "TELFIX_NUMBER"))})
        private TelEmbeddable telfixe;
        @Embedded
        @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "indicatifPays", column =
                   @Column(name = "MOBILE_COUN_COD")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "numeroTelephone", column =
                   @Column(name = "MOBILE_NUMBER"))})
        private TelEmbeddable mobile;
        @Embedded
        @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "indicatifPays", column =
                   @Column(name = "FAX_COUN_COD")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "numeroTelephone", column =
                   @Column(name = "FAX_NUMBER"))})
        private TelEmbeddable fax;
        @Size(max = 15)
        @Column(name = "EXPORTER_POSTOFFICE_BOX")
        private String chargerpostofficebox;
        @Column(name = "PRIORITE_INTEGRATION")
        private int priority;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exportateur")
        private List<EMPCertEmpotage> certificats;
        @JoinColumn(name = "EXPORTER_COUNTRY", referencedColumnName = "COUNTRYID")
        @ManyToOne
        private CorePays exporterCountry;
        @Size(max = 80)
        @Column(name = "EXPORTER_CITY")
        private String exporterCity;
    //.....
    }
```

the table will be generated from the entity

but when inserting this error is occurred

```
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("WEBAPP"."EMP_EXPORTATEUR"."NUM_CONT")
```

I do not know from where comes the column NUM_CONT

Comment: have you checked the DB? How do you generate the tables? the column must be there, otherwise there would be no constraint violations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your workspace for `EMP_EXPORTATEUR` table name, make sure that you don't use it in any other `Entity`